# Ubuntu , Apache2 , Django ) Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding ImportError: No module named 'encodings'

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to set up my **django(1.8)** application with **AWS EC2** having **Ubuntu 14.04 , Apache2 , python 3.4.**

When I run 'sudo service apache2 start' , the page keeps re-loading and the same error message is stacking at '/var/log/apache2/error.log'.

The error message is

> [Fri Aug 26 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid n:tid m] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.5.5 Python/3.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Fri Aug 26 2016] [core:notice] [pid n:tid m] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>   **Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>   ImportError: No module named 'encodings'**

My configuration is below :

I added one line: `'Include /etc/apache2/httpd.conf'`  at the bottom of `'/etc/apache2/apache2.conf'`.

> '/etc/apache2/httpd.conf'
>   :

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/project/project/project/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/ubuntu/project/project
WSGIProcessGroup project
WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/python3.4

<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/project/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/ubuntu/project/project/deploy_to_server/
<Directory /home/ubuntu/project/project/deploy_to_server>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I think I did it all done without something wrong.

But it keeps logging with the same error.
Is there anything I'm missing?

I did change `mod_wsgi/3.x Python/2.7 configured` --> `mod_wsgi/4.5.5 Python/3.4.3 configured` for synchronizing the python version ALREADY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was because of the line 'WSGIPythonHome /usr/bin/pytyon3.4' in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.

Without this line, it runs without error thank you

Comment: As extra information. ``WSGIPythonHome`` if being set should refer to the directory give by ``sys.prefix`` for the Python installation. Note that ``WSGIPythonHome`` cannot be used to refer to a Python installation or virtual environment which is a different version than what mod_wsgi was compiled for. Thus if mod_wsgi compiled for Python 2.7, you cannot use it to try and force use of Python 3.5.

Comment: The key is that you need this line *if and only if* you are using a virtual environment.  If you have installed python, and your pip dependencies like django are installed system-wide - simply omit the `WSGIPythonHome` directive.

Answer (score 4):

For me it was trying to point to the python executable under the virtualenv.

#### Wrong:

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv/bin/python3.4
```

#### Correct:

```
WSGIPythonHome /path/to/virtualenv/
```

This is as described in the [WSGI documentation for virtual environments](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html).